# Getting p-values for the comparisons by cld in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, lsmeans, lmertest

The code and output below give me the interpretation that I want - i.e. the bottom two contrasts aren't significantly different but the third is different than the other two. How can I find the comparisons and p-values used for this comparison?

i.e. my goal is to test that contrast (1-2) @ target 3 is significantly smaller than the other two contrasts.

```
mod<-lmer(Mind_avg ~ MindType*Target + 1 +  (1|Subject) + (1|Category),data=dat)
m3<-lsmeans(mod,~MindType|Target)
m3u<-update(pairs(m3,by="target"),by=NULL)
cld(m3u)

contrast Target  estimate       SE      df t.ratio p.value .group  
1 - 2     3       3.502885 1.020477 6521.04   3.433  0.0006  1      
1 - 2     2      11.559040 1.022071 6521.00  11.309  <.0001   2     
1 - 2     1      11.657720 1.016615 6521.00  11.467  <.0001   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
   > pairs(m3u)
     contrast            estimate       SE      df t.ratio p.value
     1 - 2,1 - 1 - 2,2 0.09867925 1.441574 6521.00   0.068  0.9974
     1 - 2,1 - 1 - 2,3 8.15483466 1.440444 6521.02   5.661  <.0001
     1 - 2,2 - 1 - 2,3 8.05615541 1.444300 6521.02   5.578  <.0001
```